# How to parse an octal string as a float in Rust?

Tags: parsing, floating-point, rust

I need to take an octal string, such as "42.1", and get a float from it (34.125).  What's the best way to do this in Rust?  I see [there previously was a from_str_radix function, but it's now removed](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/deprecate-f-32-64-from-str-radix/2405).

Comment: Where are these octal floating numbers coming from? Maybe it is easier to fix source? BTW, octal "42.1" is 34.125.

Comment: Apparently, the implementation was actually broken. And it seems that (from the link you provided) "If by pure chance someone has a terrible use case for which they need this, they can damn well write their own. It’s rather easy if you’re only interested in one particular radix, especially since exponents aren’t legal for bases other than 10 and 16. Besides, it can’t possibly be more inaccurate than the current implementation."

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity for a crate, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this question, a crate has appeared that solves this: [lexical](https://crates.io/crates/lexical). Compiling with the `radix` feature enables a `parse_radix` function, which can parse strings into floats with radices from 2 to 36.

Answer (score 0):

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct ParseFloatError {
    _private: (),
}

impl ParseFloatError {
    fn new() -> ParseFloatError {
        ParseFloatError { _private: () }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for ParseFloatError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Could not parse float")
    }
}

pub fn parse_float_radix(s: &str, radix: u32) -> Result<f64, ParseFloatError> {
    let s2 = s.replace(".", "");
    let i = i64::from_str_radix(&s2, radix).map_err(|_| ParseFloatError::new())?;
    let count = s.split('.').count();
    let fraction_len: usize;
    match count {
        0 => unreachable!(),
        1 => fraction_len = 0,
        2 => fraction_len = s.split('.').last().unwrap().len(),
        _ => return Err(ParseFloatError::new()),
    }
    let f = (i as f64) / f64::from(radix).powi(fraction_len as i32);
    Ok(f)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", parse_float_radix("42.1", 8).unwrap());
}
```

It first parses the input as an integer and then divides it by radix^number_of_fractional_digits.

It doesn't support scientific notation or special values like infinity or NaN. It also fails if the intermediate integer overflows.

Comment: I'm trying to get this into a crate, but I'm not sure what license to use for something you've written

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt I hereby license the above code under [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/). Though I don't really think that this code has the quality necessary for a general purpose crate. In particular, the integer overflow issue is problematic.

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/parse_float_radix is now up, but I do agree it's not likely to be useful for many purposes